# Effective and efficient deployment

Tags: managed-package, deployment, ant, package.xml

**Goal:**  Identify changes related to a requirement, deploy and verify successful deployment within 30-60 minutes (Ideally 10 minutes).  This should include any Apex code, profile, permission, field access, reports, picklist values, customization/integration with 3rd party managed package - custom fields on managed object (lookup, formulas)

**Outline of what I've tried**

1. Learn and configure Ant Migration Tool
   https://www.sfdcnotes.com/2019/04/02/salesforce-ant-migration-tool-tutorial/
2. Connect to an org (org A) and use this tool to create package.xml
   https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/
3. run Ant retrieveCode on org A (using the same package.xml) - this is the source
4. run ant retrieveCode on org B (using the same package.xml) - this is the target
5. run WinMerge to see all the folders and files that's different between contents of codepkg retrieved from org A vs. org B
6. copy/merge contents in org B codepkg folder from org A
7. run ant deployCode for org B (using the same package.xml)

Assuming I don't need to delete anything, the steps above doesn't seem to give me a similar deployment experience if I was doing a java or .net deployment.  There are too many pieces.  Is there a process and tool that I'm missing out on?  It takes me roughly a day to migrate and verify my changes and I have to do lots of screenshots and notes to manually update org B.  And I've tried various ways of the steps above (3 times at least)

Many thanks you for helping me sort this out.

Comment: also check out vendor devops packages like Copado, Gearset, Blue Canvas and others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using old tools and processes, which *are* indeed quite inefficient and ineffective.

The Ant-based Force.com Migration Tool can be replaced by [Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev).

Salesforce metadata should be stored in version control as the source of truth, where diffs and merges take place using the native functionality of the VCS (likely Git). In this model, your target org's state would typically be represented by a branch (perhaps `main`) in Git. Your changes from a development environment would be captured in a feature branch, and a Pull Request or diff would highlight the differences between the two. Your deployments can then be automated using Continuous Integration after you merge your changes.

While many development processes *do* still use `package.xml` manifests, source tracking (in scratch orgs and appropriately configured dev sandboxes) helps reduce this need. Further, the [Package Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model) more closely targets your goal of isolating specific changes within a functional unit.

Comment: I do want to store our metadata in Git.  And I've played with Salesforce CLI on VS.  It looks like the package.xml, folders, artefacts pulled down looks identical to the ones I played with using Ant and the package builder.  Because I didn't know how to build the package.xml that I found the package builder tool useful.  I actually copy and paste the folders and contents to swap between ant and VS.  Looks like I need to research more on package development model you reference above.

Comment: @Kaliforce Make sure you look at *unlocked* packages. Managed packages are for ISVs, and it sounds like you want this for your org(s), rather than a package to list on the AppExchange.